# np.dot output incorrect in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am getting a different result when I run this code in my terminal vs. a Jupyter Notebook.  Both are using Python 3.6 and numpy 1.13.1.

Terminal (correct solution):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vector_one = np.asarray([
... [1],
... [2],
... [1]],
... dtype=np.float32)
>>> vector_two = np.asarray([
... [3],
... [0],
... [1]],
... dtype=np.float32)
>>> dot_product = np.dot(vector_one[:,0],vector_two)
>>> print(dot_product)
[ 4.]
```

Jupyter Notebook:

```
import numpy as np

vector_one = np.asarray([
    [1],
    [2],
    [1]
], dtype=np.float32)

vector_two = np.asarray([
    [3],
    [0],
    [1]
], dtype=np.float32)

dot_product = np.dot(vector_one[:,0], vector_two)
print(dot_product)
[0.]
```

How is it possible that I am getting a different (and incorrect) result here?

EDIT: Tried inputting transposed vector directly

```
[In]np.array_equal(vector_one[:,0],np.asarray([1,2,1],dtype=np.float32))
[Out] True
[In] dot_product = np.dot(vector_one[:,0], vector_two)
[Out] [0.]
[In] dot_product = np.dot(np.asarray([1,2,1],dtype=np.float32), vector_two)
[Out] [4.]
```

Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Are you sure the Jupyter shell is launched with the proper python version? You can do `import sys; print('Python version', '.'.join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3]))); print('Numpy version', np.__version__)` to print the Python version and Numpy versions the notebook is using. I tried with Python 3.6.1, numpy 1.13.1, and got the correct result copy/pasting your input in Jupyter.

Comment: Python version 3.6.2
Numpy version 1.13.1
You and someone else I talked to got the correct result from copy/pasting my code, so I not sure what the problem could be.  Also, I've done other np.dot() with two matrices and the results were correct, only having the issue with this code specifically.

Comment: Yeah that's really weird. What does `vector_one[:,0]` look like? The same as `vector_one.T`? If the output is 0, I'd assume somehow at least one of the inputs is becoming a vector of zeros somehow. TBH I would probably reinstall Python/numpy/Jupyter (more accurately just create a new virtual environment and delete the old one) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: vector_one[:,0] is correct and same issue with vector_one.T  Will try reinstall.

Comment: I did create a new environment and it is now working properly.

Comment: That's great news! Really bizarre behavior you found indeed.